# Flash AS2: Event for restricted text input

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a restricted editable textfield in flash like this:

```
oField.restrict = "0-9";
```

To capture changes I attach this listener:

```
oField.onChanged = function(){
    trace(1);
};
```

Is there a listener to capture the event when a restricted character is entered (e.g. the event when the key "a" is pressed - the field does not change, so onChanged does not fire).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a "key down" listener to the stage or textfield. see if that fires...